# How can I save a project file as a bundle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, bundle, product

I'm working on an app that needs to save some data and images together into a project file. I assume this project file will have to be some sort of bundle. An example of this would be a project file in Cakewalk SONAR, an audio editor.

To be more precise, I'm working on an application that creates trivia games. When the user exports a game project as the finalized "end product," it will include text and images. This is the "bundle" that I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can always save the files to folder and use some archivator like zip with password. And you can rename the file extension to something like .bnd or .prd

Answer (score 0):

File, Save As..., select "Sonar Bundle (.CWB)" as file type.